# ionic: on-scroll-complete does not get called when scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, dom-events

The title kind of gives it away already :-)

The event 'on-scroll-complete' of the ionic-framework works fine when I use a finger to scroll the view (or when I point and drag the mouse within that view).

My problem arises when I scroll with the mouse-wheel. The 'on-scroll-complete' remains silent in that case.

Anbody help?